# How to use Conversion Service in Spring MVC 4 JavaConfig?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I am facing a problem with a migration from Spring Mvc 4 Xml to JavaConfig.

I have a xml config that works perfect with conversion

```
<bean id="objectMapper" class="com.xetec.flexmaint.common.Jackson2ObjectMapperFlexmaint" />

<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" conversion-service="conversionService">
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>       
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.xetec.flexmaint.common.JodaLocalTimeConverter"/>
            <bean class="com.xetec.flexmaint.common.JavaUtilDateConverter"/>
            <bean class="com.xetec.flexmaint.common.JodaDateTimeConverter"/>
            <bean class="com.xetec.flexmaint.common.JodaLocalDateConverter"/>
            <bean class="com.xetec.flexmaint.common.JodaLocalDateTimeConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Jackson2ObjectMapperFlexmaint

```
public class Jackson2ObjectMapperFlexmaint extends Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
        getObject().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL).setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
        Hibernate5Module hibernateModule = new Hibernate5Module();
        hibernateModule.disable(Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
        hibernateModule.enable(Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);
        getObject().registerModules(new JavaTimeModule(), hibernateModule);
        getObject().configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        getObject().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        getObject().setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to convert from Xml Config to Javaconfig/annotation.

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {

        registry.addConverter(new LocalTimeConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new JavaUtilDateConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new ZonedDateTimeConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new LocalDateConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new LocalDateTimeConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new StringToZonedDateTimeConverter());


    }
}

@Bean(name = "validatorBeanFactory")
public HibernateValidatorDefaultMessagesBeanFactory validator() {
    return new HibernateValidatorDefaultMessagesBeanFactory();
}
```

Using command line if I send a json property(**"scheduledStart":"2015-08-21T16:07:30"**) I got **HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '
{
    "title": "New JSON",
    "scheduledStart":"2015-08-21T16:07:30",
    "assetId": "2",
    "workOrderStatus": {
        "workOrderStatusID": "1"
    },
    "partDtoList": [
        {
            "barcode": "1440169305037",
            "quantity": "1"
        }
    ]
}
' -b ~/Downloads/cookies2.txt http://localhost:8080/flexmaintwebservice/api/workOrder/formCreate
```

Field sheduledStart

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.ZonedDateTimeType")
private ZonedDateTime scheduledStart;
```

If I try the same command line using Xml Config works, why?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

My entire Java Config class

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({
    "classpath:webServiceConfig.properties",
    "classpath:config.properties"
})
@ComponentScan({
    "com.xetec.flexmaint.webservice",
    "com.xetec.flexmaint.controller.validator",
}) 
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${apiUrl}")
    private String basePath;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {



        registry.addConverter(new LocalTimeConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new JavaUtilDateConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new ZonedDateTimeConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new LocalDateConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new LocalDateTimeConverter());
        registry.addConverter(new StringToZonedDateTimeConverter());

    }

    @Bean
    public JSONDocController documentationController() {
        List<String> packages = Arrays.asList("com.xetec.flexmaint.webservice", "com.xetec.flexmaint.common.helper", "com.xetec.flexmaint.entity.entity");
        JSONDocController jsonDocController = new JSONDocController("1.0", basePath, packages);
        jsonDocController.setPlaygroundEnabled(true);
        jsonDocController.setDisplayMethodAs(MethodDisplay.URI);
        return jsonDocController;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "validatorBeanFactory")
    public HibernateValidatorDefaultMessagesBeanFactory validator() {
        return new HibernateValidatorDefaultMessagesBeanFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping beanNameUrlHandlerMapping() {
        return new BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(jackson2ObjectMapperFlexmaint().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperFlexmaint jackson2ObjectMapperFlexmaint() {
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperFlexmaint();
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver url = new TilesViewResolver();
        url.setOrder(1);
        return url;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver url = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        url.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        url.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/tiles/");
        url.setSuffix(".jsp");
        url.setOrder(2);
        return url;
    }

    //TODO How to migrate this?
    /**
     *  <wss:binding url="/asset">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#assetControllerWs" />
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>

    <wss:binding url="/barcodeScannerWs">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#barcodeScannerWs" />
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>

    <wss:binding url="/maintenanceWebServiceWs">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#maintenanceWebServiceWs" />
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>

     */
}
```

ADD Controller Mapping

```
@Api(name = "work order services", description = "Methods for managing work orders")
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/workOrder")
public class WorkOrderRestFulApiController extends AbstractBaseController {

    @ApiMethod(description = "Api for create work order")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/formCreate", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json;charset=utf-8", produces="application/json;charset=utf-8")
    @ApiResponseObject @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createWorkOrder(@ApiPathParam @RequestBody WorkOrderDto workOrderDto, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
          ...
    }
}
```

Add Stack Trace

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Text '2015-08-21T16:07:30' could not be parsed at index 2 (through reference chain: com.xetec.flexmaint.webservice.dto.WorkOrderDto["scheduledStart"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '2015-08-21T16:07:30' could not be parsed at index 2 (through reference chain: com.xetec.flexmaint.webservice.dto.WorkOrderDto["scheduledStart"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:224)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '2015-08-21T16:07:30' could not be parsed at index 2 (through reference chain: com.xetec.flexmaint.webservice.dto.WorkOrderDto["scheduledStart"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1474)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:341)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3736)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2810)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:221)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-08-21T16:07:30' could not be parsed at index 2
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1777)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.deserialize(InstantDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.InstantDeserializer.deserialize(InstantDeserializer.java:45)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:520)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:339)
    ... 85 more
```

Comment: Can you also show us the stack trace, and the controller mappings that you have?

Comment: Hi, there is no stack trace on the server side, this error shows only in the console

HTTP Status 400 - </h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.28

Comment: If I remove that field works, something wrong with conversion service

Comment: That would mean the request doesn't bind properly. What is the controller mapping?

Comment: I don't think the problem is the Controller mapping because it works with Xml Configuration

Comment: Still it could be because you might have something on the RequestMapping could be determining what kind of data it accepts.

Comment: Right! I use a simple pojo annotated with @RequestBody.  How can I debug that request? Do you know with first Filter Spring will call? Thanks

Comment: basically what the stack trace tells you is that the jackson thing can't convert the field "scheduledStart". Dunno why it would work with an xml but not with a json. What type of data is the scheduledStart field? joda's DateTime?

Comment: I use Java 8 Date Time(private ZonedDateTime scheduledStart;)
I suspect the problem is in addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) it won't work properly as a <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">

Comment: I don't see a formatter for ZonedDateTime in your conversion bean

Comment: Sorry I changed Joda Time for Java 8 Date but I didn't change the Converter name, now I changed and add StringToZonedDateTimeConverter.

Comment: The problem is my Converters are never called and throws the Exception (Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-08-21T16:07:30' could not be parsed at index 2) because I use different pattern(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss) but this don't happen with Xml Configuration.

Comment: Remove the bean definition for `requestMappingHandlerMapping` and `beanNameUrlHandlerMapping`. Yours override the default configured and basically turn the whole interceptor, formatters etc. configuration useless.

Comment: Hi, I removed these bean definitions and still the same Exception(Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-08-21T16:07:30' could not be parsed at index 2).